# Plotting histogram in Python with frequency percentage

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a list of ratings for which I am plotting a histogram. On the left (y-axis) it shows the count of the frequency, is there a way for it to show the % based on traffic.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.hist(item['ratings'], bins = 5)
ax.legend()
ax.set_title("Ratings Frequency")
ax.set_xlabel("Ratings")
ax.set_ylabel("frequency")
ax.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='k')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use countplot try using the seaborn library it will make it very easy to do data visualization

```
import seaborn as sns   
sns.countplot()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is for a assignment where we can only use matplotlib.